# extract data.frame() from group_by()

Tags: r, dataset, dplyr

I'd like extract a data.frame produce by group_by() function of the dplyr package on R.

My original data looks like this:

```
   nb   site  wincod    od     cg
1 7073  ama      1 0.005351899  0
2 7129  ama      1 0.080931646  0 
3 7130  ama      1 0.446781435  0
4 7131  ama      1 0.451162869  0
5 7132  ama      1 0.992270042  0
... ... ...     ...  ...       ...
```

What I'd like is to have every group by "site" and "wincod". I tried this:

```
as.data.frame(group_by(tab_OD,site,wincod))
```

But it doesn't return the data frame I want.
I could do it by:

```
groupe1 <- filter(tab_OD,site=="ama",wincod==1)
groupe2 <- filter(tab_OD,site=="ama",wincod==2)
...
groupeN <- filter(tab_OD,site=="che",wincod==1)
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Try: `with(tab_OD, split(wincod, site))`. You can use `list2env` afterwords if you want them all as separated data frames in the global environment (not recommended though)

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I want. I just added this line: `tab_OD$site_wincod<-with(tab_OD,paste(site,wincod,sep="_"))` and then `tab_OD.grouped<-with(tab_OD, split(od,site_wincod))`

Comment: You can do this in one line, such as `with(tab_OD, split(od, paste(site, wincod, sep = "_")))` will post as an answer

Comment: The point of `dplyr`'s `group_by` function is precisely that you _don't_ have to split your data into several small buckets in order to do you analysis/transformations because it lets you do grouped operations while the data is structured as a single object (data.frame).

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that I need to extract data for a C++ program, and so I cannot use the `group_by` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively use `split` in order to create a list of `data.frame`s based on condition, such as

```
with(tab_OD, split(od, paste(site, wincod, sep = "_")))
```

Or (per Hadleys comment)

```
with(tab_OD, split(od, list(site, wincod)))
```

Comment: Better to do `split(od, list(site, wincod))`

Comment: @hadley, thanks. Didn't think it through obviously, as it wasn't OPs original quesiton